# How to Export to a PDF file in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Using VB 6 and Crystal Report 8.5

In client system while generating the report, I clicked export to PDF button in the report; it displayed Export, Export Option. Choose Export file is not displaying in the client system.

But in my system, it was displayed it displayed Export, Export Option. Choose Export file. But in client system is not showing the choose export file screen.

I cannot able to save a report file in pdf. Because it was not asking a file name to save.

Can any one help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
Private Sub ExportReportToPDF(ReportObject As CRAXDRT.Report, Byval FileName As String, Byval ReportTitle As String)
   Dim objExportOptions As CRAXDRT.ExportOptions
   ReportObject.ReportTitle = ReportTitle
    With ReportObject
        .EnableParameterPrompting = False
        .MorePrintEngineErrorMessages = True
    End With

   Set objExportOptions = ReportObject.ExportOptions
    With objExportOptions
        .DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
        .DiskFileName = FileName
        .FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat
        .PDFExportAllPages = True
    End With

    ReportObject.Export False 

End Sub  

Private Sub Command1_Click()
        Dim objCrystal As CRAXDRT.Application
        Dim objReport As CRAXDRT.Report

        Set objCrystal = New CRAXDRT.Application
        Set objReport = objCrystal.OpenReport(ReportFileName, 1)  

        ExportReportToPDF objReport, "c:\foo\foo.pdf", "foo" 
End Sub
```

Comment: In my system, Is asking a file name to save, But in Client system is not asking a file name to save?

Comment: @adatapost - Export PDF is already built in function in Crystal Report 8.5, Why should i Have to write a code for Export to PDF. In my System is aksing a file name to save.  But in Client system export PDF screen is displaying, but it is not asking a file name to save.

Comment: @Gopal - We export to PDF on a client system every day.  We prompt our users for the file name and set the filename in the export options as above.  It should just work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on Windows 8.1 x64, the solution was to:

1. locate, on the dev machine, the folder %programfiles%\Seagate
   Software\Shared
2. copy crtslv.dll and ExportModeller.dll from the
   dev machine to the C:\windows\SysWOW64\ folder
3. open a command prompt with administrator's privileges
4. register both crtslv.dll and ExportModeller.dll with regsrv32
5. Retry the pdf export...

That's all.

Comment: this worked for me when trying to save the report to a file. I was trying to save in RTF but was unsuccessful. That solved it.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Setup crystal report..
2)  Copy crxf_pdf.dll copy from c:\windows\crystal to c:\windows\system32 folder inside…
3)  Then problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a deployment problem with the Crystal files. Check the user has a file called u2ddisk.dll on their machine - this file is required for Crystal 8.5 to give the option to export to file. Otherwise it'll select the Export to Application option instead. The availability of items in the Export Format and Export Destination dropdowns is dependend on the dlls present, and it sounds like you're missing Export To Disk from the Destination dropdown.