# How can I convert a crystalreport to a text document and send it to printer

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have designed a crystal report and when i send it to printer it waste a lot of paper. So I think if  it is possible to convert the crystalreport and send it to printer then I can save my paper. 
If this is not possible then help me design a text document using c#.

This is my code to print crystalReport

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Store.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from finalbill where billno='" + textBox1.Text + "' order by slno", con);
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            da3.Fill(ds3, "finalbill");
            BillPrintReport abc = new BillPrintReport();
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = abc;
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            int i;
            int rawKind = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].PaperName == "4x6")
                {
                    rawKind = (int)GetField(printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i], "kind");
                }
            }
            abc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)rawKind;
            abc.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

           this.Close();
        }

 private object GetField(Object obj, String fieldName)
        {
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            return fi.GetValue(obj);
        }
```

Comment: try to convert it to pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356588/how-to-export-to-a-pdf-file-in-crystal-report

Comment: Its irrelevant  to my question